# Need Help Freeing Disk Space

Tags: virtualbox, disk, disk-usage, log, disk-management

I need help freeing up diskspace, From Disk Usage Analyzer it says that my Log Files have taken up more than half of the Disk Space. Is there a way to get clear up the Log Files? I've tried to delete the .gz files but the terminal says I don't have permission.

I am using a virtual box for Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rinzwind how? I'm a total beginner in this

Comment: See the answer. You use "sudo" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo rm /var/log/*.gz
```

will delete every compressed log from /var/log/. The current active logs will remain in the directories.

Before you do that

```
du -hc /var/log/*.gz
```

will show a grand total at the bottom showing you what the size is of what will be removed by the `rm` command as per file what the size is. This grand total should not be that high (on a server that is running 425 days I have 380k in total and it has apache, mysql, postgres, tomcat and jasperserver running all adding to /var/log/). If though this is a high number I would suggest you investigate -why- these logs are large and fix the problem it is logging if any or to turn down the amount of logging (by not logging regular messages but just errors and warnings).

Comment: Disk Usage Analyzer says that something in var/log is taking up alot of gigabyes.